# Has there ever been a cryptid proven to exist?

Tags: zoology, cryptozoology

Has there ever been a [cryptid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptid) proven to exist? A creature that general scientific consensus had regarded as being a myth for a long time, but finally proven to be real.

Comment: Doesn’t the [list of cryptids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cryptids) answer this question conclusively?

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph:  +1 for that list.  Here's another list which I hope you'll find very amusing -- my favourite is the Hugag (which one is your favourite?):  http://www.fearsomecreaturesofthelumberwoods.com/mainindex.htm

Comment: MONGOLIAN DEATH WORM!

Comment: @Monkey - MDW is not strictly speaking a cryptid - it was conclusively confirmed by reputable scientists (e.g. Efremov).

Comment: @DVK still my favorite!

Comment: If you're ever in Portland, ME, and are interested in cryptids, check out [Loren](http://www.lorencoleman.com/index.html) [Coleman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loren_Coleman)'s [International Museum of Cryptozoology](http://www.cryptozoologymuseum.com/). Yes, it's a small operation, but it's still pretty neat.

Comment: the moment it's proven to exist, it's no longer a cryptid :)

Comment: Good answers all, but let's not forget that Mountain Gorillas were believed to be a native myth well into the 20th century.

Comment: What is the claim to be skeptical of here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are three confirmed animals on the list Konrad Rudolph provided:

- [Dingiso (or Bondegezou)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dingiso)
- [Hoan Kiem turtle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoan_Kiem_turtle) and
- [Cuvier's beaked whale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuvier%27s_beaked_whale)

(Though the turtle is most likely actually an already known species, just in an odd and not-usually-seen location.)

Two that are oddly (to me) not on the list are probably the most famous:

- [Okapi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi)
- [Giant squid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_squid)

Comment: The giant squid was my first reaction, too, but apparently it was never a cryptid: even though it has only recently been captured on film, dead specimen have been found many times before, and credible live sightings have also occurred throughout history.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: I guess that just points to the idea that this isn't an exact science by any means, that one man's cryptid is another man's... something.

Comment: the giant squid was a cryptid for centuries, a story told by sailors and not believed until "scientists" themselves found carcasses.

Comment: There is also the Colossal Squid but I'm not sure it was ever a Cryptid, but still only discovered 1925 from beaks in Sperm Whale stomachs.

Comment: Giant Squid is on the list as Kraken.

Comment: kraken in European mythology at least is an octopus, not a squid :)

Answer (score 10):

I can't work out whether the [Platypus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platypus) counts.

The story goes that when the first Platypus specimen was sent to England, it was perceived to be a fake ([Ref](http://www.eumyeducation.com/EUMY-SBM-01-classification/mammals.htm)) by the scientist, Dr George Shaw, who examined it with a pair of scissors in an effort to expose the fraud ([Ref](http://www.platypus.asn.au/historical_background.html)).

(The unreferenced web-sites I have checked differ in a few minor details: was it more than one naturalist who was doubtful? Can the scissor marks still be seen in the British Museum's specimen? I can't be sure.)

If one bloke from a museum in England can be counted as "general scientific consensus" (and perhaps, in 1799, he could!) then the platypus must count as a cryptid!

(There's a similar story about black swans, but I found even less evidence.)

Comment: given the upheaval around the piltdown man at the time, the platypus was indeed considered suspicious until someone from the royal society shot one and disected it :) http://www.kingsnake.com/toxinology/old/mammals/platypus.html contains a reference.

Comment: @jwenting: Uh, the Piltdown man hoax was 100+ years later.

Comment: hmm, must have my timelines wrong. But it does illustrate the concept of faked biological specimens :)

Comment: I have forgotten the generic word for fakes like the Feejee Mermaid (a grotesque? something like that), but they existed pre-European discovery of the platypus.

Comment: Also, the platypus would not be considered a cryptid because they had a specimen in hand, however odd it seemed at the time. Stories and scant evidence (footprints, etc) of it before a specimen was in hand would have labeled it a cryptid.

Comment: This [article and interesting video](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-17193936) (best practical use of a 3D printer I've seen!) shows an example of the sort of thing I was talking about - and calls them "monkey fish". It dates the study of them in the 20th Century, which is later than I expected.

Answer (score 9):

Mountain Gorillas were cryptids back in the 1800's, before being a cryptid was cool.

[List of former cryptids](http://listverse.com/2010/08/13/top-10-cryptids-that-turned-out-to-be-real/), including gorilla.

[image: Gorilla combat]

[Page 686](http://www.flickr.com/photos/stevelewalready/1251648477/)

[Sea and Land by J. W. Buel, 1889](http://www.flickr.com/photos/stevelewalready/sets/72157600541886427/detail/?page=7) 
The chapter is called "The Gorilla- does he exist?"

[Gustave Doré](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustave_Dor%C3%A9) did most of the etchings for the work.

Comment: Ah, the Hipster among the cryptids?

Comment: Well, 'cryptids' only showed up in the nineties, so the gorilla's got something to be proud of. Fearsome warriors they were too, pre-discovery. http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cryptid&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=0